# Entity Model Zero to Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, relationship, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables named as
1. **SubProcedure**
2. **UnitReference**
3. **TestReference**

Here i am having the following conditions

1. A **Subprocedure** should have atleast one **UnitReference**
2. A **SubProcedure** Can have **Zero** or **Many**  **TestReferences**
3. A **TestReference** should have **SubProcedure** and **UnitReference**

TestRefernce Table Records Will be like this

Here's an TestRefenceTable Image link to [TestReferences](http://i569.photobucket.com/albums/ss139/vsatya91/testref_zpsrcahnqwo.jpg).

And My Existing Entity Model Diagram link is  [ExistingModel](http://i569.photobucket.com/albums/ss139/vsatya91/existingModel_zps7c5gtnvf.png).

I am not able to post my image here so that i have added reference link for the diagram .

My Questions is

1. How can i represent relation between  **SubProcedure** => **UnitReference** .
2. How can i represent relation between  **UnitReference** => **TestReference** .
3. How can i represent relation between  **SubProcedure** => **TestReference** ..

I want to ensure my existing relationship between three tables is correct , If its wrong means please guide me to correct it .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not exactly sure what the question is - is there an issue you are having? Can you explain it for us?

Comment: Yes, i want to ensure my existing relationship between three tables is  correct or not , If its wrong means please guide me to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model looks fine, and does what you want it to; specifically:

- Each `UnitReference` can have many `SubProcedure`s
- Each `SubProcedure` can have many `TestReference`s
- A `UnitReference` can have many `TestReference`s

If that is what you want then you have done it correctly.

One thing I would note though is that you have redundancy in your model. You can navigate from `UnitReference` to `TestReference` via two different paths: directly, or via `SubProcedure`. This means that one of these relationships is redundant. Let me explain using LINQ method syntax:

```
//To get all SubProcedures for a UnitReference
context.UnitReferences.Find(UnitReferenceId).SubProcedures;

//To get all TestReferences for a UnitReference
context.UnitReferences.Find(UnitReferenceId).TestReferences;

//instead of the line above you could use the other relationship like this
context.UnitReferences.Find(UnitReferenceId).SubProcedures.SelectMany(s => s.TestReferences);
```

There is nothing *wrong* with having redundancy - it can be quite useful. Just be aware that you have two separate relationships to maintain in the case of an update. For example, if you wanted to move a `TestReference` from one `SubProcedure` to another, you need to update the `.SubProcedure` property of the `TestReference`, but **also** the `.UnitReference` property to the `.UnitReference` property of the new `SubProcedure`, or the data will be inconsistent.